# @DateTimeFormat not recognized

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to make `LocalDateTime` object be annotated with `@DateTimeFormat`
why is it not recognizing it?

My main idea is that once a string is received in the controller, it will convert it into LocalDateTime object

[image]

at the moment I'm getting:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1493708443198,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message": "Could not read JSON document: Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalDateTime: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2015-09-26T01:30:00.000')\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3233297a; line: 5, column: 23] (through reference chain: net.petrikainulainen.spring.trenches.model.Topic[\"localDateTime\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalDateTime: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2015-09-26T01:30:00.000')\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3233297a; line: 5, column: 23] (through reference chain: net.petrikainulainen.spring.trenches.model.Topic[\"localDateTime\"])",
  "path": "/api/topics"
}
```

when trying to post

```
 {
     "id": "javaw2",
     "name": "java code",
     "descript2ion": "java description",
     "localDateTime": "2015-09-26T01:30:00.000"
 }
```

this is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/topics")
public void addTopic(@RequestBody Topic topic) {
    topicService.addTopic(topic);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalDateTime: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2015-09-26T01:30:00.000')

The error states that LocalDateTime class does not have String argument constructor/factory method hence you have to write your own **deserializer** to deserialize the `Date` string representation into `LocalDateTime` Object.

Something like :

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyDateDeserializer.class)
private LocalDateTime localDateTime;
```

then `MyDateDeserializer` implementation

```
public class MyDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer< LocalDateTime > {
  @Override
  public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws Exception {

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("your pattern");

    String date = jp.getValueAsString();

    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
    return localDateTime;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to annotate the field with `@DateTimeFormat` as it's already into the format recognized by Jackson. All you need to do is to add `JavaTimeModule` into `ObjectMapper` configuration so that it can deserialise the String into `LocalDateTime`. Here's an example:

**Model:**

```
class Model {
    private LocalDateTime date;

    public LocalDateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

**Deserialization:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String json = "{\"date\" : \"2015-09-26T01:30:00.000\"}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    Model model = mapper.readValue(json, Model.class);
    System.out.println(model.getDate());
}
```

To do this, you will have to use Jackson version 2.8.5 or above, [here's](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) the documentation.